# ¿Cómo completar fechas según condiciones lógicas en R?

Tags: r

Tengo una serie de participación de empresas en ciertas áreas en distintos momentos del tiempo. Necesito completar la serie temporal, siguiendo el criterio de que me repita la cantidad de filas según el número de empresas que participan en dicho momento del tiempo.

Es decir, yo tengo originalmente el siguiente dataset:

```
fecha <- c("2009-01-01", "2009-01-01", "2009-02-01", "2017-08-01", "2017-08-01", "2017-08-01", "2017-09-01")
empresa <-  c("A", "B", NA, "C", "D", "E", NA )
area <-  c("zona 1", "zona 1", "zona 1", "zona 2", "zona 2", "zona 2", "zona 2"  )
participacion <-  c(0.5, 0.5, NA, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, NA)

DF <- data.frame(fecha, empresa, area, participacion)

   fecha    empresa   area     participacion
1 2009-01-01       A zona 1           0.5
2 2009-01-01       B zona 1           0.5
3 2009-02-01    <NA> zona 1            NA
4 2017-08-01       C zona 2           0.4
5 2017-08-01       D zona 2           0.3
6 2017-08-01       E zona 2           0.3
7 2017-09-01    <NA> zona 2            NA
```

Pero necesito algo como lo siguiente:

```
   fecha      empresa  area     participacion
1  2009-01-01       A zona 1           0.5
2  2009-01-01       B zona 1           0.5
3  2009-02-01       A zona 1           0.5
4  2009-02-01       B zona 1           0.5
5  2017-08-01       C zona 2           0.4
6  2017-08-01       D zona 2           0.3
7  2017-08-01       E zona 2           0.3
8  2017-09-01       C zona 2           0.4
9  2017-09-01       D zona 2           0.3
10 2017-09-01       E zona 2           0.3
```

Es decir, la condición lógica que necesitaría es: si `empresa` es `NA`, buscá cuantas empresas hay en la fecha anterior y agregá dicha cantidad de filas para la fecha correspondiente.

Alguna idea de cómo resolverlo?

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, necesitamos tratar la fecha como tal y no como un `factor`:

```
DF$fecha <- as.Date(DF$fecha)
```

Luego, lo que haremos es:

1. Obtenemos las filas de fecha/area faltantes
2. La unimos mediante un `join` con las filas correctas, para llegar a obtener cual es la fecha de la que correspondería obtener los datos (`fecha_copia`)
3. Con esa `fecha_copia` hacemos nuevamente un `left_join` con los datos correctos para generar la información de las filas faltantes
4. Juntamos mediante un `union_all` las filas "correctas" y las generadas por filas "faltantes"

Algo como esto:

```
library("tidyverse")

DF %>% 
  # Obtenemos las fechas/areas faltantes
  filter(is.na(empresa)) %>%
  distinct(fecha, area) %>% 
  # Hacemos un join con las fechas/areas "correctas"
  left_join(DF %>% 
              filter(!is.na(empresa)) %>% 
              distinct(fecha, area), by="area") %>% 
  # Agrupamos cada faltante para obtener
  # la máxima fecha correcta anterior
  group_by(fecha.x, area) %>% 
  filter(fecha.x >= fecha.y) %>% 
  summarise(fecha_copia=max(fecha.y)) %>% 
  # Por cada faltante ahora sí, obtenemos las filas
  # que le corresponde de los datos correctos
  left_join(DF, by=c("area", "fecha_copia" = "fecha")) %>% 
  select(fecha=fecha.x, empresa, area, participacion) %>% 
  # Llegamos a generar las filas para cada faltante
  # y ahora simplemente unimos todo con las filas 
  # del df orginal que fueran las "correctas"
  union_all(DF %>% 
              filter(!is.na(empresa))
  )
```